# PDFKit y Node JS; al crear documento PDF ¿Como enviarlo desde el servidor al cliente?

Tags: nodejs, pdf, express

mi problema es el siguiente; tengo una aplicación web creada con NodeJS que muestra un formulario donde los usuarios agregan datos que incluirá un documento PDF creado con PDFKit, al dar clic en el botón *submit* del formulario se crea el documento y éste permanece del lado del servidor, el código es el siguiente:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/pagar',function(req,res){
 var nombre = req.body.nombre;
    var apellidoPaterno = req.body.apellidoPaterno;
    var apellidoMaterno = req.body.apellidoMaterno;
    var fs = require('fs');
    var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
    
    var pdf = new PDFDocument({
        //size: 'LEGAL', 
        layout: 'landscape',
        size: [210, 210], 
        margin: 5,     
        info: {    
             Title: 'Recibo de agua potable',
             Author: 'Comite de agua potable 2018',
        }  
    });

    // Write stuff into PDF
    pdf.moveDown()
         .fillColor('black')
         .fontSize(7)
         .text('EJEMPLO DE DOCUMENTO PDF', {
           align: 'center',
           indent: 2,
           height: 2,
           ellipsis: true
         });
         

    pdf.moveDown()
         .fillColor('black')
         .fontSize(7)
         .text('NOMBRE DE PERSONAS DESDE FORMULARIO', {
           align: 'center',
           indent: 2,
           height: 2,
           ellipsis: true
         });
          


     pdf.moveDown()
         .fillColor('black')
         .fontSize(8)
         .text('NOMBRE: '+nombre+' '+ apellidoPaterno +' '+ apellidoMaterno , {
           align: 'left',
           indent: 2,
           height: 2,
           ellipsis: true
         });


      // Stream contents to a file
     pdf.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(nombre+"_"+apellidoPaterno+"_"+apellidoMaterno+'.pdf')).on('finish', function () {
        console.log('Archivo creado satisfactoriamente ....');
     });
 
     pdf.end();

});

module.exports = router;
```

Sin embargo, quisiera que el documento PDF se envié al cliente para que se pueda imprimir ya que al ingresar a la aplicación web (desde una maquina cliente) y agregar los datos al formulario éste se crea pero del lado del servidor.

Ojala me pudieran ayudar.

Comment: el truco es enviar en el content-type el tipo pdf cuando le den click al usuario se le descargara automaticamente, otra opcion es usar el visor de google par el pdf de igual formas generar una url para el archivo

Answer (score 1):

Para poder enviar el documento al cliente como respuesta debe hacer lo siguiente:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    router.post('/pagar',function(req,res){
    var nombre = req.body.nombre;
    var apellidoPaterno = req.body.apellidoPaterno;
    var apellidoMaterno = req.body.apellidoMaterno;        
    var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

    var pdf = new PDFDocument({        
      layout: 'landscape',
      size: [210, 210], 
      margin: 5,     
      info: {    
         Title: 'Recibo de agua potable',
         Author: 'Comite de agua potable 2018',
      }  
    })
    pdf.pipe(res)
    pdf.end()
    })
    module.exports = router;
```

Para generar el documento no es necesario usar el modulo **fs** de javascript. Una consideracion adicional y es que en esta sección de código no se agrega contenido, pero se puede visualizar desde el lado del cliente.